# Opencart - Select products with all selected attributes

Tags: php, mysql, filter, opencart, having

i am using opencart and i have made some filters in product list, where the admin can select product attributes and filter the products.

For now, i choose eg. watt=11 and volt=240, it shows the 5 products that have 11 watt and 5  products that have 240volt, 10 products.

BUT i want to show only the products that have BOTH 11 watt AND 240volt.

The attributes in var_dump are the following:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["attribute_id"]=> string(2) "17" ["values"]=> string(4) "[11]" } [1]=> array(2) { ["attribute_id"]=> string(2) "18" ["values"]=> string(6) "[240]" }
```

This is the code i use
The join

```
if(!empty($data['filter_product_attributes'])) {
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_attribute pa ON (p.product_id = pa.product_id)";   
}
```

I add all attributes in the string $attribute_ids seperate the ids and in attribute_texts seperate the texts and from below use AND...IN

```
$sql .= " AND pa.attribute_id IN (".$attribute_ids.")";
$sql .= " AND pa.text IN (".$attribute_texts.")";
```

I have tried HAVING clause ($ids and $texst are arrays) but it does not work as expected:

```
$sql .= " HAVING";

$idc = 0;
foreach($ids as $id) {
    if($idc == 0) {
      $sql .= " sum(pa.attribute_id = ". $id .") > 0";  
    }
    else {
      $sql .= " and sum(pa.attribute_id = ". $id .") > 0 ";
    }
    $idc +=1;
}

        $txc = 0;
        foreach($texts as $text) {
                $sql .= " and sum(pa.text = ". $text .") > 0";  

        }
    }
```

How can i show the products that have ALL attributes selected? Any ideas?

Comment: If you use a `LEFT JOIN` everything from the LEFT (first) Table will be included. Try using an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Should i leave this also or do i have to change it? $sql .= " AND pa.attribute_id IN (".$attribute_ids.")";
$sql .= " AND pa.text IN (".$attribute_texts.")";

Comment: Thanks @EliSadoff that worked! :)